# AES San Francisco (Nov. 2010)

Tags: aes, conventions, networking

**EDIT/UPDATE:** So I'm in San Francisco now, and the convention starts tomorrow. Figured I'd refresh this to see if anyone else is going to be in attendance. Also, I'm going to try and run some end of the day posts on my site for anything I find interesting. If there's any particular info or gear you'd like me to check out, leave a response and I'll see what I can do. ;)

---

And how many days will you be there? Just going to the floor show, or are you going to the conference sessions as well?

I'll be there; arriving on the 3rd and leaving on the 8th. I'll be wandering the floor and the sessions.

Who wants to meet up?

Comment: Can you buy me an authentic Champion San Francisco Giant's cap while you're there? :-)

Answer (score 1):

I've compiled a list of everyone that I know who is going so far - about 10 people long at this point - and I'll be sending out an email in about a week or so to put together a get together.

I will be there from Nov. 3 - 8th as well. I'm aiming to do the get together Friday or Saturday night.

I will be attending a few of the sessions as well as roaming the floor.

I'll be up in DC this Saturday and Sunday. I'm meeting with Steve and Karol - you should get in on that and I can fill you in on the rest of the details.

Comment: sounds good to me...i still haven't met karol yet. lol

Comment: @shaun - she's amazing! Steve's a very lucky guy.

Comment: Yes, I up-voted that ^

Comment: Sorry I missed the opportunity to meet with them whilst in LA…better luck next time --

Comment: I've up-voted Steve's up-voting his wife ^

Answer (score 1):

I'm not attending, but I'm local, so I'd love to hook up for drinks, dinner, or similar!

Comment: sounds good to me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to be there on Sunday. 
I'm a 6'5" lanky white dude with brown hair.

-Kevin Crawford